# Replace <a href=> links to <img src=> images

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to find/replace links to images.

For example, the following text:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/arbitrary-file.jpg">Text</a>
```

to

```
<img src="http://domain.com/arbitrary-file.jpg" />
```

Comment: Do you mean to replace the tags?

Comment: In the browser, right?

Comment: Find and Replace is a great utility to do this.

Comment: So you are trying to click on a text and turn it into an image, right?

Comment: Did you mean putting image inside the link?

Comment: You can use jquery for this. .`replaceWith` method can be used

Comment: Note you can't put 'Text' in the image tag.  Perhaps you meant alt="Text"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way to do it in jQuery:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<img src='" + $(this).attr("href") + "'>")
})
```

Image tags don't have inner text. So you would just turn `<a href="http://placehold.it/255x255">Something</a>` into `<img src="http://placehold.it/255x255">`

Edit: if you want to add alt text as what the inner text was you could do:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<img src='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' alt='" + $(this).text() +"'>")
})
```

Here's a snippet you can run:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<img src='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' alt='" + $(this).text() +"'>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://placehold.it/255x230">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var linksNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var i = 0; i < linksNodes.length; i++ ) {

    var a = linksNodes[i];
    if( a.href.endsWith(".jpg") || a.href.endsWith(".png") ) {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = a.href;
        a.parentElement.replaceChild( img, a );
    }

}
```

`endsWith` is in ES6 but IE11 doesn't support it, Edge does, however. You may need to extend `String`:

```
if( !String.prototype.endsWith ) {

    String.prototype.endsWith = function(value) {

        var expectedIdx = this.length - value.length;
        return this.indexOf( value, expectedIdx  ) == expectedIdx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://domain.com/arbitrary-file.jpg" class="test">Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var attrib = jQuery('a.test').attr('href');
jQuery('a.test').removeAttr('href');
jQuery('a.test').attr('src',attrib);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i;
var currentLink;
var newImg;

for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

    currentLink = links[i];

    newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = currentLink.href;

    currentLink.parentNode.insertBefore(newImg, currentLink);
    currentLink.remove();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Jquery.

stepa:

1. First take `<a>` tag  into `div` tag.Give unique id to `div` tag:
   `<div id='divtag'><a href="http://domain.com/arbitrary-file.jpg">Text</a>  </div>`
2. `var value= $('#divtag a').attr('href')`
3. `$('#divtag').text('<img src="+ value +">Text</img>')`.

Follow above step to complete your work as you need.